# Adding muliple authors in a conference paper

Tags: xetex, pdftex, templates

I am trying to add four authors in a confernce paper. The code for adding it is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{eacl2017}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\eaclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%\def\eaclpaperid{***} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here

%\setlength\titlebox{5cm}
% You can expand the titlebox if you need extra space
% to show all the authors. Please do not make the titlebox
% smaller than 5cm (the original size); we will check this
% in the camera-ready version and ask you to change it back.

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

\title{Instructions for EACL-2017 Proceedings}

\author{AbC123 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Abc123 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\

  BAC23

  }

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  This document contains the instructions for preparing a camera-ready
  manuscript for the proceedings of EACL-2017. The document itself
  conforms to its own specifications, and is therefore an example of
  what your manuscript should look like. These instructions should be
  used for both papers submitted for review and for final versions of
  accepted papers.  Authors are asked to conform to all the directions
  reported in this document.
\end{abstract}
```

This code gives me an error.

```
Runaway argument? {AbC123 \\ Affiliation / Address line 1 \\ Affiliation / Address line\ETC. Paragraph ended before \author was complete. <to be read again> \par l.48
```

How to fix it?
I am using the template provided here

```
http://eacl2017.org/images/site/eacl-2017-template.zip
```

Comment: Please add a full MWE. Maybe it's just your uppercase `\and`?

Comment: You cannot put blank lines in the argument of `\author`.  Also, do **not** use `\tt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions in `eacl2017.sty` tell you to use `\AND` for starting a new row of authors and to modify the value of `\titlebox` if it's too short to contain the author data.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{eacl2017}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % <--- better than "times"
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\eaclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%\def\eaclpaperid{***} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here

\addtolength\titlebox{1cm} % if necessary
% You can expand the titlebox if you need extra space
% to show all the authors. Please do not make the titlebox
% smaller than 5cm (the original size); we will check this
% in the camera-ready version and ask you to change it back.

\title{Instructions for EACL-2017 Proceedings}

\author{AbC123 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\And
  Abc123 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\AND
  Abc123 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\And
  Abc123 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain}\\
  }

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  This document contains the instructions for preparing a camera-ready
  manuscript for the proceedings of EACL-2017. The document itself
  conforms to its own specifications, and is therefore an example of
  what your manuscript should look like. These instructions should be
  used for both papers submitted for review and for final versions of
  accepted papers.  Authors are asked to conform to all the directions
  reported in this document.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\And`(horizontal positioning):

```
\author{A1\\
Affiliation / Address 1 \\
Affiliation / Address  2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
\\\And%  next author <-------------------------here
B2\\
Affiliation / Address  1 \\
Affiliation / Address  2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
\\\And%  next author <-------------------------here
C3\\
Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
\\\And%  next author <-------------------------here
D4\\
Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
}
```

Or `\newline` (vertical positioning).  \

```
\author{A1\\
Affiliation / Address 1 \\
Affiliation / Address  2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
\newline \\ %  2.row  <-------------------------here
\textbf{B2}\\ % bold author in row 2
Affiliation / Address  1 \\
Affiliation / Address  2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
\\\And
C3\\
Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
\newline \\ %  2.row  <-------------------------here
\textbf{D4}\\ % bold author in row 2
Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
{\tt email@domain} \\
}
```